# didInsertElement event trigged before insert child elements

Tags: javascript, ember.js

To use [colorselector](http://bootstrap-colorselector.flaute.com/) plugin, the `colorselector()` function should be called after
render the select with options in browser. But, using ember `didInsertElement` doesn't works because the callback is triggered before insert the `<option>` tags!

I tried this:

```
App.ColorSelector = Ember.Select.extend({
  _initialize: function() {
    console.log(this.$().find('option').size()); // logs 0
    this.$().colorselector();
  }.on('didInsertElement');
});

App.ColorSelector = Ember.Select.extend({
  _initialize: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
      console.log(this.$().find('option').size()); // logs 0
      this.$().colorselector();
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement');
});
```

**Edit:**
using the @SeanK suggestion:

```
App.ColorSelector = Ember.Select.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
      console.log(this.$().find('option').size()); // logs 0
      this.$().colorselector();
  }
});
```

How to run the `colorselector()` function call after ember insert the `<select>` with all `<option>` tags?

Comment: Try moving your console.log call to be after your call to colorselector().  You're outputting the size before its ever inserted.  Does that change the log output?

Comment: Don't change @SeanK. The problem is: when the function didInsertElement is called, the options are not inserted yet. I need to move `colorselector()` call to after Ember insert all <option> tags.

Comment: Ah, I see, so the content you specified on the tag in the template is not yet in the DOM.  That is strange.  How did you set up your content array?  I'm curious what happens if you add a delay to your call to colorselector().  Try including it inside an Ember.run.later call and give it a delay, of say a half second, and see if that changes things.

It's also possible that the Ember.Select view is not the right choice in this case - it may not mesh well with something like Bootstrap.  You could try creating your own custom view or component instead.

Comment: A "mutation event" ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent)) which watches changes made in the DOM, user-triggered or not. That handler could catch when the `option` elements are added to the `select` and you could do your thing. However, this could slow down the app, so use it once and remove the handler, then you call the color selector thing. Not super strong solution tho.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe, i think that Ember has one way to do this simply. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220989/ember-js-how-to-apply-a-jquery-plugin-after-new-item-is-inserted-to-arraycontro)

Comment: How exactly are you're populating this select again?

Comment: Have you tried putting in this._super() in your didInsertElement function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, but the problem wasn't the component. The content of component was an [PromiseArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html), which I created in `setupController` function:

```
setupController: (controller, model) ->
  this._super(controller,model);
  controller.set 'colors', this.store.find 'color'
```

And when the `didInsertElement` function is called, the array isn't fulfilled yet.
To solve this problem, I added this condition:

```
{{#if colors.isFulfilled }}
  {{color-selector content=colors value=color }}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works just fine for me on Ember 1.7.0

```
App = Em.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    colors: ['blue', 'green']
});

App.ColorSelector = Ember.Select.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log(this.$().find('option').size()); // logs 2
    //this.$().colorselector();
  }
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('color-selector', App.ColorSelector);
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{color-selector content=colors}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try overriding the didInsertElement function and calling colorselector() from there instead of having a function observe didInsertElement?

```
App.ColorSelector = Ember.Select.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().colorselector();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Seank, this doesn't works too. I edited my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as a best practice, you should be doing something like this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  colors: ['blue', 'green']
});

App.ColorSelector = Ember.Select.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
    },

  afterRenderEvent: function(){
     console.log(this.$().find('option').size()); // logs 2
     this.$().colorselector();
  }
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('color-selector', App.ColorSelector);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ember.run.next()`:

```
App.ColorSelector = Ember.Select.extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
      var self = this;
      Ember.run.next(function() {
         self.$().colorselector();
      });
   }
});
```